# Why won't my image files upload in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload, input-type-file

I want my users to be able to upload images to their account (my MySQL database). However, when I try to encode it and upload it, it appears that the file was never uploaded and is empty. I have checked the maximum upload size etc. in my PHP settings. Thanks in advance!!

```
$data = "";
if(isset($_FILES["up"])) {
   $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['up']['tmp_name']);
   $data = base64_encode($data);
   $data = $connection->real_escape_string($data);
} else {
   echo '<div style="position:absolute;height:100px;top:0px;left:0px;
                     border-top-right-radius:20px;border-top-left-radius:20px;
                     width:100%;background:white;z-index:100;"
          >
            <font style="color:#BB0000;font-size:2.2vw;">'.$_FILES['up']['error'].'</font>
        </div>';
   die('');
}
```

My HTML is: (And the form submits correctly)

```
 <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" name="up" id="up"/>
```

Comment: What a horrible way to store files.

Comment: yeah, store the file in the file system and store the name in the database

Comment: do you have  enctype="multipart/form-data" in your html form?

Comment: e4c5 - Why is that better though?

Comment: This is the worst way to upload file. Do, two things, 1. Upload the file in the server using a php function move_uploaded_file() and 2. Then store that file name in the database.

Comment: Okay, I have updated it to do that. But i am still getting no file when trying to send it through the form

Comment: Suggestion: make a directory like 'userPhotos'. Upload the photos to this directory. store its path in the database. i.e, photo : userPhoto/12345.jpg

Comment: You need to do the debugging by checking if the file upload was successful at all. $_FILES has an error element as well, the minimum is to check its value and share it with us (if you cannot resolve the issue based on its contents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: store the images in a directory.

why not DB you ask?

1. read/write to a DB is always slower than a filesystem
2. your DB backups will become more time consuming

so, here is my solution.

STEP 1: create a directory userPhotos

STEP 2: create a form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Select your profile picture:
 <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
 <input type="Upload" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

STEP 3: create a file called upload.php which handles file uploads.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "userPhotos/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$newfilename = ;//assign unique user ID
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"][$newfilename.$imageFileType], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";$uploadOk = 1;
} 
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
if($uploadOK==1){
 store the path of image in DB as "/userPhotos/".$newfilename
 echo "uploaded photo : <img src='userphotos/".$newfilename."'">
}
//to display the image fetch the path using user ID as put it in src of img tag. 
?>
```

Let me know if anyone has a better solution. thanks and Good luck.

Comment: Okay. I have most of that already in, but do I have to have file type="upload" for my submit button? I'm hoping the image could be part of the signup form

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Code**

```
$data = "";
if(isset($_FILES["up"])) {
   $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['up']['tmp_name']);
   $data = base64_encode($data);
   $data = $connection->real_escape_string($data);
} else {
   echo '<div style="position:absolute;height:100px;top:0px;left:0px;
                     border-top-right-radius:20px;border-top-left-radius:20px;
                     width:100%;background:white;z-index:100;"
          >
            <font style="color:#BB0000;font-size:2.2vw;">'.$_FILES['up']['error'].'</font>
        </div>';
   die('');
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" name="up" id="up"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I dont see any difference? I have the enctype included now

Comment: Than you can use move_uploaded_file() function instead of "base64_encode()"

Comment: Oh yes okay, but the problem is that it isnt sent in the form

Comment: function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb");
    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($base64_string));
    fclose($ifp);
    return $output_file;
}

Comment: You don't want to set with form?